# Redirect sub domain A to https domain B

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect

I've tried looking for a post related to my issue but I couldn't find a suitable one. If there is, let me know!

Here's the current situation that I'm facing now. I would like to redirect a domain,

> example.hr

that is being used with another server and there's an SSL that comes with it.

Now, I have another server that comes with the domain,

> example.co

and there's an SSL cert too.

I would like to redirect test.example.hr to https://example.co. How can I go about to do this? I'm testing it with the subdomain since the root domain is in used.

I've tried this method,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.hr
        ServerAlias www.test.example.hr
        Redirect / https://example.co/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.co
    ServerAlias www.example.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The SSL configuration is inside the 443 block.

When I go to test.example.hr, it will change to https://test.example.hr and the error that comes up is "Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information from test.alt.hr (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and update me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.hr
        ServerAlias www.test.example.hr
        Redirect / http://example.co/

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
        </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.co
    ServerAlias www.example.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

make sure to enable `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: It redirects now but on the address bar, it is showing 'Not Secure' since it doesn't match with the SSL cert example.co

Comment: It must redirect https://example.co . Are you trying some wildcard redirection I.e. https://*.example.co? If so your certificate should also have a wildcard in it.